# What is difference between ZK Rollups and Polygon?

Tags: ether, polygon, zksnark, layer-2

ZK Rollups and Polygon mainnet are both layer 2 solution built for ethereum scaling solution. So what's the difference between these two solutions and which one to prefer?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://hackernoon.com/polygon-vs-optimistic-and-zk-rollups-an-in-depth-comparison-dn2035c6) is a pretty good article explaining this in details.

Hope this helps

Comment: could you paraphrase it in your answer please